# What does Use Host GPU mean in Android studio?

Tags: android, performance, android-emulator

when I was configuring my AVD for the emulator I came across the following term --"Use Host GPU" . Should I check it or not ?Will that speed up my emulator or is it going to slow down . Waiting eagerly for the answer . Any help is appreciated .

Comment: Have you tried googling? http://android.stackexchange.com/a/51741

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using the option, you allow your emulated device to use the physical GPU of your computer instead of emulating it in software.

As a result, your virtual device will run more smoothly.

Comment: Please can you explain what is a physical GPU ?

Comment: This is simply the graphics card you have in your computer. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphics_processing_unit

Comment: how do i active this on android studio emulator ?

Answer (score 0):

"Use Host GPU" will forward graphics calls to your PC's graphics processing unit. This speeds up graphics-intensive apps, and allows you to run apps that utilize OpenGL ES.